# Writing to virtual port using Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qt5

What I'm trying to do is write string to the serial port from the windows 7 host machine to the /dev/ttys0 in the guest Ubuntu machine.

I tested this using putty on both the host and guest machine. The data is written to the /dev/ttys0 from  \.\pipe\COM1.

Now I want to use a simple QT5 program using this virtual serial port to write a string to the guest putty.

The problem I have is that the program isn't able to open this port , below is the Qt program.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSerialPort serial;
    qDebug() << " Serial communication starts .. ";
    serial.setPortName("\\.\pipe\COM1");
    if(serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
     {
        serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
        serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

        serial.write("blah blah");

      }
    else
        qDebug() << " Serial port isn't open : " << serial.errorString();
    while(serial.canReadLine())
    {
        qDebug() << " serial.readLine()" ;

    }

    serial.close();
    return a.exec();
}
```

the output of the debug :

```
Serial communication starts .. 
Serial port isn't open :  "No such file or directory"
```

Comment: I think you need more black slashes to escape the other correctly, try `\\\\.\\pipe\\COM1` or `R"(\\.\pipe\COM1)"`

Comment: @Niall that didn't work, it gives me the serial error of "incorrect function"

Answer (score 0):

What is the software you use to run your virtual machine with Ubuntu??
If, it's VM Ware Workstation you can edit the preference of the VM and add a serial port.

Comment: It's VM VirtualBox. But It looks like the problem is on Qt side since it is unable to open the serial port properly. Maybe that the API is made for physical port, and to make work for Vritual port necessitate some other steps....no ?

Comment: You shutdown your VM and click on "edit virtual machine settings". Next you click on "Add" (require admin privilege). You select Serial Port and push  click on next. You can select if you want real COM or file .

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you there, When I go to the setting of the VM virtualbox I don't see anywhere "add/" require admin privilege"

Comment: Sorry i see Vmware instead of VirtualBox